# Регулярное выражение d+

Tags: массивы, регулярные-выражения

Доставая из текста 6 чисел, которые идут через пробел,  регулярным выражением d+, получается не целое число, а каждая цифра отделена запятой.
Пример : "3 5 77 32" после использования выражения d+, получаю "3, 5, 7, 7, 3, 2".
Подскажите, пожалуйста, регулярное выражение, чтобы избавиться от пробелов и получить целое число без запятых. Спасибо.

Comment: `d*` может? Или не помогло?

Comment: Но `\d+` точно должно работать. можете показать ваш код? Вот посмотрите тут https://regex101.com/r/rFXM2D/1

Comment: Вы точно написали не `\d+` а `\d`.

Comment: Да, точно, я не могу понять, почему цифры выделяются запятыми? Почему не дает целого числа?

Comment: Вы не пробовали `s.replace(/\D+/g, '')`? Какаой язык программирования?

Answer (score 0):

Такое может быть, если в движок регулярок использует "не жадный режим" (non greedy mode). А вот как его выключить (хотя по умолчанию все известные движки используют как раз жадный) - это уже нужно смотреть конкретную реализацию.

Вторая возможная причина -это то, что между цифрами на самом деле есть невидимый пробел (или другой подобный символ).

В любом случае, пишите язык и среду, а также точный пример кода, как используете.

Comment: То есть нужно включить жадный режим?

Comment: да, в этом случае плюс будет забирать по максимуму.

Comment: Спасибо, я попробую.

Comment: Не получается...

Comment: Показывайте код. Иначе никак Вам не помочь.